# How to add to a Current Value method for a calculator

Tags: java, class, methods

I am creating a memory calculator. In my code, I have a current value method and need it to return a new value when the operator either decides to add, subtract, multiply, etc... I am having trouble with figuring out how to change the current value field. When i chose to add a number to the current value, the value stays the same as before, 0.

FIRST CLASS

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemoryCalculator {
private double currentValue;

    public static int displayMenu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add ");
        System.out.println("2. Subtract ");
        System.out.println("3. Multiply ");
        System.out.println("4. Divide ");
        System.out.println("5. Clear ");
        System.out.println("6. End");
        System.out.println("Please choose which math operation to perform, or press 6 to quit.");

        int selection = input.nextInt();

        return selection;

    }
    public static double getOperand(String prompt) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);

        double operand = input.nextDouble();

        return operand;

    }
    public double getCurrentValue() {
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
        return currentValue;

    }
    public void add(double operand2) {
        this.currentValue = getCurrentValue() + operand2;
        getCurrentValue();

    }
    public void subtract(double operand2) {

    }
    public void multiply(double operand2) {

    }
    public void divide(double operand2) {

    }
    public void clear() {

    }


}
```

SECOND CLASS DRIVER CLASS

```
public class MemoryCalculatorDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double operand2 = 0;

    MemoryCalculator CalcObj = new MemoryCalculator();

    System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());
    int selection = CalcObj.displayMenu();

    if(selection == 1) {
        System.out.println(CalcObj.getOperand("What would you like the second number to be"));

        CalcObj.add(operand2);

        System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());

    }else if (selection == 2) {
        System.out.println(CalcObj.getOperand("What would you like the second number to be"));

        CalcObj.subtract(operand2);

        System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());

    }else if (selection == 3) {
        System.out.println(CalcObj.getOperand("What would you like the second number to be"));

        CalcObj.multiply(operand2);

        System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());

    }else if (selection == 4) {
        System.out.println(CalcObj.getOperand("What would you like the second number to be"));

        CalcObj.divide(operand2);

        System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());

    }else if (selection == 5) {
        CalcObj.clear();

        System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());

    }else if (selection == 6) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }


}

}
```

I am able to get the selection input from the user, and I can get the first number from the user. When I chose option 1 "add", the user can input the number but, the number was not added the the current value.

Comment: public double getCurrentValue() {
        return this.currentValue;
    } No need for the rest of that code.

Comment: public void add(double operand2) {
        this.currentValue += operand2;
        System.out.println("New value: "+getCurrentValue());
    } The current value would never get printed.

Comment: Probably remove the print due to having it in the other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returns value by this method `public static double getOperand(String prompt)` but where you used returned value?

It must be like this:

```
if(selection == 1) {
        operand2 = CalcObj.getOperand("What would you like the second number to be"));
        CalcObj.add(operand2);
        System.out.println(CalcObj.getCurrentValue());

        // your code like this...
}
```